# SQLite: How to get certain field from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, web-sql

I have a WebSQL database which has three tables which all contain id's and PREFIX_name fields. I need to get all the name fields for single id.

Currently I'm trying following clause:

```
SELECT A_name FROM TableA WHERE companyId = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT B_name FROM TableB WHERE companyId = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT C_name FROM TableC WHERE companyId = 1
```

This returns the results object as expected but the field names are wrong:

```
[{
  "A_name" : "result from TableA",
 },
  "A_name" : "result from TableB",
 },
  "A_name" : "result from TableC"
}];
```

As you can see, I can't identify from which table fields are from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `UNION` results together, the column takes the name given to it in the first query (in this case `A_name`)

Instead of using `UNION ALL`, try joining your tables together:

```
SELECT A.A_name, B.B_name, C.C_name
FROM TableA A
    INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.companyId = B.companyId
    INNER JOIN TableC C ON A.companyId = C.companyId
WHERE A.companyId = 1
```

This will give you the results on a single row.  If you really want the results as seperate rows, you could perhaps select the table name along with the *_name field:

```
SELECT 'TableA' AS TableName, A_name FROM TableA WHERE companyId = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'TableB', B_name FROM TableB WHERE companyId = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'TableC', C_name FROM TableC WHERE companyId = 1
```

Comment: I already found an alternate way of using Local Database in this case. But your answer is valid, thanks :)